# C# CustomValidator not showing error but args.Isvalid = false

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a custom CustomValidator on a text box so that the length can not be 0. Except it is not showing the error message. But continuing to the Button_click event.

this is the code i'm using

```
<asp:TextBox ID="proj_title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorproj_title" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorproj_title_OnServerValidate" ShowSummary="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

The Validator:

```
    protected void CustomValidatorproj_title_OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (proj_title.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: You can replace the if/else block with `args.IsValid = proj_title.Text.Length > 0`

Comment: Are you expecting validation to occur client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what the problem was. 
The Custom Validator always continue to the button click method even if the Validator says "false" In order to catch the IsValid there needs to be an `if (Page.IsValid){}` in the click method.

Example:

```
 protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
               //code here if the page is valid
            }
        }
```

After this the custom validator triggers if the page is not valid and the message is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide ControlToValidate="proj_Title" property in your custom validator

Comment: This is the CustomValidator now: `<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorproj_title" runat="server" ControlToValidate="proj_title" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorproj_title_OnServerValidate" ShowSummary="true"></asp:CustomValidator>`

But it is now skipping the Validator: http://i.imgur.com/B3538xj.png

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have **ValidateEmptyText** set to True.